# change konsole-profile according to application in KDE

Tags: ssh, terminal, kubuntu, profile, konsole

Using the Konsole terminal-emulator with KDE on Kubuntu 9.10 , I would like to have a different konsole profile (colors, icons) whenever I ssh into a server, so I can easily spot in which konsole tab i'm on the local machine and which i'm on the remote server.
I have the different profiles set up, as for now I change that profile manually from the gui ...

Comment: should this be moved to serverfault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to alter the bashrc on the remote server, and set there a different text color.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the `user@host` prefix to the window title (which konsole can use for its tabs (`%w` in the konsole profile)).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is to [create bash aliases to connect the servers](https://abdussamad.com/archives/503-Changing-Konsole-colors-in-KDE.html). For example:

```
alias resetcolors="konsoleprofile colors=Local"
alias ssh-saturn="konsoleprofile colors=SaturnColors; ssh -X saturn; resetcolors; echo 'Welcome back'"'!'
```

Where `saturn` is the name of the server, `SaturnColors` is the desired profile when connected to the server, `Local` is your default color scheme for your localhost, and `-X` is whatever ssh flags you want to use. Now, when you type `ssh-saturn`, the konsole colors will change and you will connect to the server, after which, your color scheme will be reset (and receive a welcome back message).

This assumes that you have setup ssh keyless login.